# Python Pandas: update multiple column values from another dataframe using apply method

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I want update values of multiple columns from another dataframe
I found the solution using combine_first

'''

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id' : ['1470', '1550', '1562', '1578', '1645', '1867', '1888', '2205', '2283', '2306'],
'gp' : ['nl_i', 'adv_i', 'adv_i', 'nl_i', 'adv_i', 'early_i', 'nl_i', 'nl_i', 'nl_i', 'nl_i'],
'cho' : [69626.0, 183425.0, 75418.0, 84239.0, 158721.0, 122857.0, 166052.0, 86686.0, 140407.0, 122792.0],
'date_i' : ['2000-11-29', '2000-11-28', '2000-11-27', '2000-11-26', '2000-11-25', '2000-11-24', '2000-11-23', '2000-11-22', '2000-11-21', '2000-11-20'],
})
df1['rl'] = np.NAN
df1['date_f'] = np.NAN
```

'''
[image]
'''

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'no' : ['2939', '2283', '1578', '2781', '2319', '2306', '1888', '1470', '2869', '2205'],
'date_i' : ['2010-09-18', '2012-02-08', '2012-04-09', '2012-04-23', '2012-05-08', '2012-09-04', '2013-08-29', '2013-09-09', '2014-02-24', '2015-11-19'],
'rl'  : ['r', 'l', 'r', 'r', 'l', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r']})
```

'''
[image]
'''

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame ({'no' : ['2319', '2306', '1888', '1470', '2869', '2205'],
'date_f' : ['2019-05-10', '2013-09-24', '2019-06-12', '2016-08-29', '2016-10-10', '2017-11-30']})
```

'''

[image]

Here, 'id' of df1 is same value in 'no' of df2 and df3
I want to update ['date_i', 'rl', 'date_f'] columns from values of df2 and df3
Next dataframe is which I want

[image]

I found out this solution in stack-overflow using combine_first

'''

```
df1_new = df2.set_index('no').combine_first(df1.set_index('id')).reset_index()
df1_new.rename(columns = {'index':'id'}, inplace = True)
df1_new = df1_new[df1.columns]
df1_new.dropna(subset=['cho'], inplace = True)

df1_new = df3.set_index('no').combine_first(df1_new.set_index('id')).reset_index()
df1_new.rename(columns = {'index':'id'}, inplace = True)
df1_new = df1_new[df1.columns]
df1_new.dropna(subset=['cho'], inplace = True)
```

'''

However, I tried to solve this problem using apply method

Can I update my dataframe using apply method instead of using combine_first?

Comment: Why would you replace your current solution with `.apply(...)` version of it? What are exactly the shortcomings of the current solution?

Answer (score 0):

We combined each data frame without using apply, replaced the NaN value of the date and removed the unnecessary columns. If you really want to use the apply function, this answer will not be satisfactory.

```
df1_new = df1.merge(df2, left_on='id', right_on='no', how='left')
df1_new = df1_new.merge(df3,left_on='id', right_on='no', how='left')
df1_new['date_i_y'].fillna('', inplace=True)

for idx, row in df1_new.iterrows():
    if len(row['date_i_y']) == 0:
        df1_new.loc[idx,'date_i_y'] = row['date_i_x']

df1_new.drop(['date_i_x','no_y'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df1_new.columns = ['id', 'gp', 'cho', 'no', 'date_i', 'rl', 'date_f']

df1_new
id  gp  cho     no  date_i  rl  date_f
0   1470    nl_i    69626.0     1470    2013-09-09  r   2016-08-29
1   1550    adv_i   183425.0    NaN     2000-11-28  NaN     NaN
2   1562    adv_i   75418.0     NaN     2000-11-27  NaN     NaN
3   1578    nl_i    84239.0     1578    2012-04-09  r   NaN
4   1645    adv_i   158721.0    NaN     2000-11-25  NaN     NaN
5   1867    early_i     122857.0    NaN     2000-11-24  NaN     NaN
6   1888    nl_i    166052.0    1888    2013-08-29  r   2019-06-12
7   2205    nl_i    86686.0     2205    2015-11-19  r   2017-11-30
8   2283    nl_i    140407.0    2283    2012-02-08  l   NaN
9   2306    nl_i    122792.0    2306    2012-09-04  r   2013-09-24
```